# Rails ActiveRecord two fields each referencing the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a `Player` class that I want to have `high_school_team` and `club_team` properties. So then I figure `Player` will have `high_school_team_id` and `club_team_id` properties that point to the corresponding team. I try to do this in the following migration, but it doesn't work.

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :middle_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.decimal :height
      t.decimal :weight
      t.date :birthday
      t.references :team, :high_school_team, foreign_key: true
      t.references :team, :club_team, foreign_key: true
      t.decimal :gpa
      t.string :class_year
      t.string :intended_major
      t.string :email
      t.string :phone_number
      t.text :notes

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

It gives the following error:

```
code/scout-db [master●] » rails db:migrate
== 20191218003854 CreatePlayers: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:players)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

you can't define an already defined column 'team_id'.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:372:in `column'
...
```

`HighSchoolTeam` and `ClubTeam` are models that do single table inheritance with `Team`.

I don't see why I'm getting the error. The [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) seem to say that the first argument for `t.referenes` is `table_name` and the second `ref_name`. `:team` is the name of the table and I want the references to be `high_school_team_id` and `club_team_id`.

When I switch the order of the arguments to `t.references`, it still doesn't work. Somehow it gives the same error: `you can't define an already defined column 'team_id'.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you you are confusing [`SchemaStatement#add_reference`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) and [`TableDefinition#references`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references) which have completely different signatures.

If you want to setup a foreign key column where the table can't be derived from the name of the column (the first argument) you just pass `foreign_key: { to_table: :teams}`.

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.references :high_school_team, foreign_key: { to_table: :teams}
      t.references :club_team, foreign_key: { to_table: :teams}
    end
  end
end
```

`t.references :high_school_team, index: true` as recommended by the other answers is NOT equivilent. That just adds a index to the column but no foreign key constraint.

You can then setup the assocations on Player as:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :high_school_team, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :club_team, class_name: 'Team'
end
```

You can't use a single `has_many :players` assocation on the other end though as the foreign key column can be either `players.high_school_team_id` or `players.club_team_id`.

```
class Team
  has_many :high_school_team_players, 
     foreign_key: :high_school_team_id,
     class_name: 'Player'
  has_many :club_team_players, 
     foreign_key: :club_team_id,
     class_name: 'Player'
end
```

But really a better alternative in the first place would have been to setup a join table:

```
class Player
  has_many :placements
  has_one :high_school_team, 
    through: :placements,
    source: :team
    class_name: 'Team'
  has_one :club_team, 
    through: :placements,
    source: :team
    class_name: 'Team'
end

class Placement
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team
  has_many :placements
  has_many :players, through: :placements  
end
```

Comment: The equivilent call for `add_reference` is `add_reference(:teams, :high_school_team, foreign_key: {to_table: :teams })`

Answer (score 0):

The doc you mentioned talks about the case when you need to add reference to an existing table.

For adding a refernence to a new table:

> t.references :team, :high_school_team, foreign_key: true

This piece of code is wrong. Instead, it should be

`t.references :high_school_team, foreign_key: {to_table: :teams}`

`to_table` is needed to add [database referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)

So your migration will be like this:

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      ....
      t.references :high_school_team, foreign_key: {to_table: :teams}
      t.references :club_team, foreign_key: {to_table: :teams}
      ....
    end
  end
end
```